# how do I Freeze header and first column in Datatable Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I'm developing Flutter App using data table. In that I used two datatables to freeze first column of table but I don't how to freeze table header.

In my datatable there are lot of dynamic content, that's why unable to use packages.

So is there any way to freeze header (already did first column freeze) ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem,
I used [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html),

I need to freeze my first two column and remaining scrollable horizontally, and i made this using DataTable Widget and SingleChildScrollView,

Here i show both method first is whole table scrollable horizontally and second is work as mention above,

below code will help you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ConfirmationDetailsPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ConfirmationDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConfirmationDetailsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ConfirmationDetailsPage> createState() =>
      _ConfirmationDetailsPageState();
}

class _ConfirmationDetailsPageState extends State<ConfirmationDetailsPage> {
  Widget myDiveider() {
    return const VerticalDivider(
      color: Colors.grey,
    );
  }

  final appPrimary = Colors.purple;



  TextStyle headerTextStyle = const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 13.7,
  );

  TextStyle lableTextStyle = const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 13.2,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("17 Feb 2023"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 13,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
               const Text(
                  "Pending Member's List",
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: const [
                      Text("Share"),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Icon(Icons.share),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // const SizedBox(height: 7),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                child: DataTable(
                  horizontalMargin: 10,
                  headingRowHeight: 45,
                  headingRowColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  dataRowHeight: 40,
                  columnSpacing: 8,
                  dividerThickness: 0,
                  border: TableBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "No.",
                        style: headerTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "Member",
                        style: headerTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "Status",
                        style: headerTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "Reason",
                        style: headerTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),

                    // WhatsApp
                    const DataColumn(
                      label: SizedBox.shrink(),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                    // Call
                    const DataColumn(
                      label: SizedBox.shrink(),
                    ),
                  ],
                  rows: <DataRow>[
                    DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "1",
                            style: lableTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "Sahil Prajapati",
                            style: lableTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        const DataCell(
                          Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              size: 19,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        const DataCell(
                          Center(
                            child: Icon(Icons.warning),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
                              const Size.fromWidth(23),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
                              const Size.fromWidth(23),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.call),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "2",
                            style: lableTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "Siddharth Prajapati ",
                            style: lableTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        const DataCell(
                          Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              size: 19,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                       const DataCell(
                          Center(
                            child: Icon(Icons.warning),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
                              const Size.fromWidth(23),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
                              const Size.fromWidth(23),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.call),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              children: [
                DataTable(
                  horizontalMargin: 10,
                  headingRowHeight: 45,
                  headingRowColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  
                    border: Border(
                      top: BorderSide(color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)),
                      bottom: BorderSide(color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)),
                      left: BorderSide(color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  dataRowHeight: 40,
                  columnSpacing: 8,
                  dividerThickness: 0,
                  
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "No.",
                        style: headerTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "Member",
                        style: headerTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                  ],
                  rows: [
                    DataRow(
                      cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "2",
                            style: lableTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "Siddharth Prajapati ",
                            style: lableTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(myDiveider()),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: DataTable(
                      horizontalMargin: 10,
                      headingRowHeight: 45,
                      headingRowColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        // borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        //   topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                        //   bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                        // ),
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)),
                          bottom:
                              BorderSide(color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)),
                          right:
                              BorderSide(color: appPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      dataRowHeight: 40,
                      columnSpacing: 8,
                      dividerThickness: 0,
                     
                      columns: [
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            "Status",
                            style: headerTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            "Reason",
                            style: headerTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                        // WhatsApp
                        const DataColumn(
                          label: SizedBox.shrink(),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(label: myDiveider()),
                        // Call
                        const DataColumn(
                          label: SizedBox.shrink(),
                        ),
                      ],
                      rows: [
                        DataRow(
                          cells: [
                            const DataCell(
                              Center(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  size: 19,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DataCell(myDiveider()),
                            const DataCell(
                              Center(
                                child: Icon(Icons.warning),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DataCell(myDiveider()),
                            DataCell(
                              IconButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
                                  const Size.fromWidth(23),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                               icon:const Icon(Icons.mail),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DataCell(myDiveider()),
                            DataCell(
                              IconButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
                                  const Size.fromWidth(23),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.call),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

May be this will help you ! Thank You

Comment: I need to freeze the Table header also..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package it gives the option to free column and header

https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table